# Declaring the java file that should be executed first in a project

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a Java Project in Eclipse and i want to have one class `Start.class` being executed every time I'm launching the Project. This is my code:

```
package Hausaufgaben;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Start {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int auswahl = neueZahlEinlesen("Geben Sie\n" + "1 fuer Aufgabe 1,\n"
                + "2 fuer Aufgabe 2,\n" + "3 fuer Aufgabe 3,\n"
                + "4 fuer Aufgabe 4,\n" + "5 fuer Aufgabe 5,\n"
                + "6 fuer Aufgabe 6,\n" + "7 fuer Aufgabe 7,\n"
                + "8 fuer Aufgabe 8,\n" + "9 fuer Aufgabe 9,\n"
                + "10 fuer Aufgabe 10\nein: ");
        if (auswahl < 10 && auswahl > 0) {
            switch (auswahl) {
            case 1:
                Aufgabe1.start();
                break;
            case 2:
                Aufgabe2.start();
                break;
            case 3:
                Aufgabe3.start();
                break;
            case 4:
                Aufgabe4.start();
                break;
            case 5:
                Aufgabe5.start();
                break;
            case 6:
                Aufgabe6.start();
                break;
            case 7:
                Aufgabe7.start();
                break;
            case 8:
                Aufgabe8.start();
                break;
            case 9:
                Aufgabe9.start();
                break;
            case 10:
                Aufgabe10.start();
                break;
            }
        } else {

        }
    }

    public static int neueZahlEinlesen(String text) {
        System.out.print(text);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        return scan.nextInt();
    }

}
```

I want this Start.java to be executed first and then the user is asked to input a number between 1-10 and then the program jumps into another .java file that looks like this f.e. :

```
package Hausaufgaben;

class Aufgabe4 {

    public static void start() {
        // do sth here

    }

}
```

But I have the problem that always the last .java file I was working on is being executed, maybe anyone knows how to fix this. I'm new to java and any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your question doesn't particularly make sense. As long as you are running the project as a project the class with your main method will always be executed first.

Comment: yeah i know, but somehow it is not working...

Comment: `public static void main(String[] args)` is the entry point for your application.  Assuming there's *only one*, it will be executed first any time your application runs.  What exactly is the indication of a problem that you're experiencing?

Comment: It sounds like you have multiple `public static void main(String[] args)` methods in your project to me. You should use a Run Configuration to specify which `main()` method to call.

Comment: i figured it out it was because i created another main methode :S thx anyways^^

Answer (score 0):

You just need a main function, just call the function you want from inside it

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
     Aufgabe4 auf= new Aufgabe4 ();
     auf.start();
}
```